# MySql Procedure or function to replace mutiple spaces to single space in a string

Tags: mysql

How can I replace multiple spaces to a single space in a mysql string.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE I_hate_duplicate_spaces
BEGIN
  DECLARE rows_affected INTEGER;

  REPEAT
    UPDATE table1 SET afield = REPLACE(afield,'  ',' ');
    SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO rows_affected;
  UNTIL rows_affected = 0 END REPEAT;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now start the stored procedure:

```
CALL I_hate_duplicate_spaces;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you want to do a regular expression replacement in MySQL something like PHP's `preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $sString)` - unfortunately this isn't built into MySQL so you'd need a user-defined function ... which led me to this: [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Hope that helps...